# Cloud computing power

Tags: cloud

We have a very intensive algorithm that needs to run days on a small network of computers. What do I need to test it 'on the cloud'? We work in a Microsoft environment and the program is based on .NET Framework 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: What does this even mean? What do you mean by "test it on the cloud"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using the Microsoft development platform, you may want to look into using [Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/). It comes with plenty of development tools to help you [get started](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/getstarted/default.aspx).